# Asynchronous for loop: how do I make the for loop wait for function to finish?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm racking my brain trying to figure out how to sequence this / place callbacks to get what I need.

I have a loop that checks for the existence of files. I'd like it to callback when it's done, but the `for` loop and the callback finish before the "fs.open" finishes... typical asynchronous problem.

I am using **node v0.10.29**, **express v3.14.0**, and am looking at using the "**[async](https://github.com/caolan/async)**" library, but again, just can't figure out the logic that I need...

Here is what I have:

## Input

```
function checkForAllFiles(callback)
{
    var requiredFiles = [];
    requiredFiles[requiredFiles.length] = "../Client/database/one.js";
    requiredFiles[requiredFiles.length] = "../Client/database/two.dat";
    requiredFiles[requiredFiles.length] = "../Client/database/three.xml";
    requiredFiles[requiredFiles.length] = "../Client/database/four.dat";
    requiredFiles[requiredFiles.length] = "../Client/database/five.dat";
    requiredFiles[requiredFiles.length] = "../Client/database/six.xml";

    var missingFiles = [];
    for(var r=0; r<requiredFiles.length; r++)
    {
        fs.open(requiredFiles[r], 'r', function(err, fd){
            if(err)
            {
                missingFiles[missingFiles.length] = err.path;
                console.log("found missing file = ", err.path);
            }
        });
        console.log("r = ", r);
    }
    console.log("sending callback: ", missingFiles);
    callback(missingFiles);
}
```

## Output

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
sending callback: []
found missing file: ../Client/database/three.xml
```

## Desired Output

```
0
1
found missing file: ../Client/database/three.xml
2
3
4
5
sending callback: ["../Client/database/three.xml"]
```

Comment: Just for fun, you can use the `Array.push()` method for adding items to to your `requriedFiles` array: `requiredFiles.push("../Client/database/one.js");` for example

Comment: Will do! ;D I'll give it a go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the `reject` method in the async module (which I see you've already found).    What it will do is return an array in its callback that contains any elements that *don't* match a specified check function. For the check function, I'd recommend just using `fs.exists` instead of watching for an error on `fs.open`.

Using those functions you can actually reduce the whole check to one line.  Something like this:

```
function checkForAllFiles(callback)
{
    var requiredFiles = [];
    requiredFiles[requiredFiles.length] = "../Client/database/one.js";
    requiredFiles[requiredFiles.length] = "../Client/database/two.dat";
    requiredFiles[requiredFiles.length] = "../Client/database/three.xml";
    requiredFiles[requiredFiles.length] = "../Client/database/four.dat";
    requiredFiles[requiredFiles.length] = "../Client/database/five.dat";
    requiredFiles[requiredFiles.length] = "../Client/database/six.xml";

    async.reject(requiredFiles, fs.exists, callback);
}
```

`callback` will get called with an array that contains just the files that don't exist.

Comment: You don't need all those array set lines, you can just initialize it directly: var requiredFiles = [ '../Client/databse/one.js', '../Client/databse/two.dat', ...etc ]

Comment: Very true.  I was just copying the method in the question to try to make it a little clearer where things should go.

Answer (score 1):

Use the async library and the eachSeries method. Example:

```
async.eachSeries(array,
     function(element, next) {
          // do something with element
          next();
     }
);
```

It will sequentially go through the array and process each element. Calling next goes to the next element. Series makes sure it does it in the order of the array, otherwise the order of going through the array is not guaranteed. If you have other async functions called within it, just pass the next function around and call it when done with all the needed functions and the next array element will be processed.

Maybe something like this:

```
var missingFiles = []
async.eachSeries(requiredFiles, function(file, nextFile){
 fs.open(file, 'r', function(err, fd){
        if(err)
        {
            missingFiles[missingFiles.length] = err.path;
            console.log("found missing file = ", err.path);
        }
       nextFile();
    });
    console.log("r = ", file);
});
console.log("sending callback: ", missingFiles);
callback(missingFiles);
```

Comment: If you don't need the checks to happen in order, you can use `async.each` which should run faster. Also, you can use `fs.exists` instead of `fs.open` and if all your required files are in the same directory, you can use one `fs.readdir` call to get the list of files in that directory and do an intersection with your `requiredFiles` array.

Comment: This was definitely worth a shot but for some reason, the callback still kept getting executed after the fs :( even when I used the eachSeries(arr, iterator, callback) syntax :(